# How to set weight/score dynamically in sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I am fetching matching results for a query. For example, I have a searchable column in my table `name` of students so if I enter "Mack" as a query then it retrieves all matching records name with "Mack". Something like "Mack Paul", "Mack Rhodes", "Mack" and so on.

But, I want to get best match first which is "Mack" and then remaining like "Mack Paul", "Mack Rhodes" and so on.

I am new to sphinx and don't know how to prioritise results set based on exact match first and then rest.

> Is there any way to get results based on priority or score to column
>   values?

Answer (score 0):

Well in theory `SPH_RANK_SPH04`
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#builtin-rankers

> additionally boosts the matches when they occur in the very beginning or the very end of a text field. Thus, if a field equals the exact query, SPH04 should rank it higher than a field that contains the exact query but is not equal to it.

Otherwise ideas inlcuding using the field length to affect the weight, see http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-index-field-lengths

or could try rewriting the qyery

```
$cl->Query("Mack | ^Mack$");
```

... theory should rank the exact match higher, as it matches both terms. Although you may have to also play with RANKER to get this to actually change the rank in a meaningful way.